# Android 6.0+: No Sound Using the New MIDI API

Tags: android, midi

I am using the [new MIDI API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html) in order to play some MIDI notes. However, I am unable to hear any sound, nor any exception is being thrown. The code for the same is as follows:

```
//initialising the MidiReceiver
private MidiReceiver midiReceiver;
midiReceiver = new MidiReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onSend(byte[] msg, int offset, 
        int count, long timestamp) throws IOException {

    }
};

/*Then in my loop containing note_on or note_off events*/
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
int numBytes = 0;
int channel = 2; // MIDI channels 1-16 are encoded as 0-15.               
// NOTE_STATUS is either 0x90 or 0x80
buffer[numBytes++] = (byte)(NOTE_STATUS + (channel - 1)); 
buffer[numBytes++] = (byte)noteValue; // the required MIDI pitch
buffer[numBytes++] = (byte)127; // max velocity
int offset = 0;
midiReceiver.send(buffer, offset, numBytes);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I think it must be because the `onSend` method is empty. How do I use it in order to make my app play back the note(s) within the Android device?

Comment: Well, your `onSend` function appears to be empty. What do you expect what an empty function does?

Comment: I suspected the same. Could you please tell me how do I use that function in order to start a playback for a note? Also, I'll edit the question including this point.

Comment: The page you linked to shows how to send MIDI to some device.

Comment: You're correct. I copied the code and used a MidiReceiver instead of a MidiInputPort, but I can't hear any sound.

Comment: How about *not* changing the code?

Comment: I now understand where I was wrong in phrasing my question. I actually wanted to hear the sound within the phone, but the documentation provides information for MIDI programming using an external MIDI device. Thanks for the heads up, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any indication in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary.html) that the new MIDI API actually let you synthesize audio, so, it seems you need to generate the sound yourself.

Maybe [this library](https://github.com/billthefarmer/mididriver) might be useful.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your input. I was using https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android this library in order to playback the notes, but the playback is quite slow even for faster sequence of notes. I use an AsyncTask to play the notes using this library. I'll also try the library you mentioned to see if it improves the performance.

Comment: You can try it, I just googled it, what I wanted to point out is that the new midi api doesn't provide any method to synthesize the sound, it can just let you communicate with midi devices and make your app be a midi device itself